# copy input from one table to another table on same document

Tags: javascript

Please I want to use javascript to copy input from one table to another table on same document. There are 2 tables. In the first table, the user will input desired value. These values will be used as column headers in the 2nd table. So far I am not getting it with my script. Please you experts will know what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PrtQual</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif; padding: 0px;
margin-left: 0px; margin-left: 50px; max-width: 800px;}
p, table {margin-left: 25px;}
th {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; border-style: solid; 
margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse; border-spacing: 0px;}
td {font-weight: Normal; font-size: 14px; border: 1px; border-style: solid; 
margin: 0px; border-colapse: colapse; border-spacing: 0px;}
.hide {display: none;}
.show {display: display;}
.hove: hover {background-color: rgb(250,250,150);}
.btn {padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; background-color: rgb(240,240,240); margin-    
left: 25px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border: 
1px; }
.btn:hover {background-color: rgb(250,250,150)}
</style>

<script  
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="main">
<tbody>
<tr class="hide">
<td id="ddnfmat"><input type="text" class="hove"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PrtQual</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Index</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="ddn"><input type="text" class="hove" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><i> To add a new header, click on the button below</i></p>
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="addNewheader()" value="Add new  
factor">
<br><br>
<input class="btn" type="button" onclick="copyheader()" value="Finish">
<br><br>
<table id="exp">
<thead>
<tr id="exphdr">
<th>s/n</th>
<th>PrtQual</th>
<th>Index</th>
<th id="ddnO"><input type="text" readonly /></th>
<th id="ddnT"><input type="text" readonly /></th>
<th id="ddnTh"><input type="text" readonly /></th>
<th>Comment</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
function addNewheader() {
    var table = document.getElementById('main');
    var elmnt = table.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
    var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(cln);
    var p = document.getElementById('main').rows.length;
    var q = p - 1;
    var s = document.getElementById('main').rows[q];
    s.setAttribute("class", "show"); 
}
</script>

<script>
function copyheader() {
         for (i=3, i<6, i++) {
             tableheader(i)
         }
 }
</script>

<script>
function tableheader(i){
    var tble = document.getElementById('main');
    var mytr = tble.getElementByTagName('tr')[i];
    var mytd = mytr.getElementByTagName('td')[0];
    var myinput = mytd.getElementByTagName('input')[0];
    var myval = myinput.value;

    var tbl = document.getElementById('exp');
    var hdr = tbl.getElementByTagName('tr')[0];
    var hddata = hdr.getElementByTagName('td')[i];
    var inp = hddata.getElementByTagName('input')[0];
        inp.value = myval;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are loading jQuery but you don't use it, why? Traversing the DOM is so much easier with jQuery than with plain javascript.

Comment: For one thing, getElementByTagName should be getElementsByTagName (plural). Use the browser console to check what errors you're getting.

Comment: Your for loop is also wrong, use semicolons not commas: `for ( var i = 3 ; i < 6 ; i++) `

Answer (score 1):

As m69 mentioned there are wrong method names. After that the for loop was defined incorrectly. After those changes the code didn't error out except for it using the wrong selector.  In your second table you're trying to select and operate on `<TH>` not `<TD>` which is why "hddata" was undefined.

```
<script>

    function addNewheader() {
        var table = document.getElementById('main');
        var elmnt = table.getElementsByTagName("TR")[0];
        var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild(cln);
        var p = document.getElementById('main').rows.length;
        var q = p - 1;
        var s = document.getElementById('main').rows[q];
        s.setAttribute("class", "show");
    }

    function copyheader() {
         for ( var i = 3 ; i < 6 ; i++) {  // the loop was previously using comma separators in place of semicolons
             tableheader(i)
         }
     }

    function tableheader(i){
        var tble = document.getElementById('main');
        var mytr = tble.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i];  // all these method calls were misspelled
        var mytd = mytr.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
        var myinput = mytd.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        var myval = myinput.value;

        var tbl = document.getElementById('exp');
        var hdr = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
        var hddata = hdr.getElementsByTagName('th')[i];      // select TH tags here NOT TDs!
        var inp = hddata.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            inp.value = myval;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Very grateful Works fine now. I have learn one word today PATIENCE to check every detail in scripts. My sincere thanks to all. l I will move to jquery very soon after I am fully OK with javascript. I appreciate.

Comment: Checking every detail is a Very Good Thing, but an even better lesson here would be to learn how to use the debugging tools available to you. Take some time to explore the JavaScript debugger available in your favorite browser. It will tell you *exactly* what is wrong when you have these kinds of errors. Here's an introduction to the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).